# Is Haitian Creole morphology fusional?

Tags: morphology, linguistic-typology

There are conflicting views regarding how Haitian Creole is classified in relation to its lexifier--French. I am trying to give a good description of Haitian Creole in terms of its morphology. Is Haitian Creole considered to be fusional in its morphological structure? I know that many have argued that its morphosyntax and other properties are more closely aligned with West African languages, such as Fongbe.

Comment: Haitian Creole is more analytical than French, but languages are not perfect examples of a typology.  Standard spoken French itself is hardly the best example of a fusional language, and its trajectory over the last millennium is towards being more analytical.  Moreover, in diglossic situations like this one where the two languages are related, speakers often slide along the spectrum during the day or even within a conversation, that is, there are transitional forms.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer that's (a pretty good) answer, not a comment!